# How do I change this regex rule to not accept parentheses?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex rule (in PHP) to find image links in a text document:

```
'/((f|ht)tp)(.*?)(.gif|.png|.jpg|.jpeg)/'
```

So it accepts, for example, the following:

```
http://www.example.com/image.jpg
```

However, I want it to **not** accept the following:

```
(http://www.example.com/image.jpg)
```

OR:

```
[http://www.example.com/image.jpg]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm looking for these strings in a larger string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a job for [negative lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
'/(?<![(\[])((f|ht)tp)(.*?)\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)(?![)\]])/'
```

`(?<![(\[])` asserts that there is no `[` or `(` before the start of the match, and `(?![)\]])` asserts that no `)` or `)` follows after it.

**Edit:**

Don't forget to escape the dot if you want to match a literal dot.

Comment: PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 56

Comment: @RichardRodriguez: I just noticed that, I've fixed the typo. Please try again.

Comment: I'd prefer `\[|\(` to `[(\[]`.

Comment: @Dukeling: Why? Character classes are faster than alternations (although it may be that PHP will optimize single-character alternations into character classes anyway).

Comment: I find it more readable. I didn't say it'd be better, just that I'd prefer it. And the speed difference shouldn't be anything to worry about.

Comment: This works, but seems to be not accepting the original image links. Any idea why? For example, this string fails: ``http://f.cl.ly/items/1D1s3f293B072d0c2z0D/2013-05-22%2016.51.13.jpg``

Comment: It seems like if the link is at the end of the string, it passes correctly. If anything follows after it, it doesn't.

Comment: @RichardRodriguez: Sorry, another typo. My apologies...should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is missing `^` and `$`. Try out this pattern:

```
^((f|ht)tp)(.*?)(.gif|.png|.jpg|.jpeg)$
```

Comment: OP said its within a larger string